# Eclipse - How do I view java arrays / collections better in debugger

Tags: arrays, eclipse, debugging, visualization

Viewing/Searching java arrays and collections in the Eclipse Java debugger is tedious and time-consuming.

I tried this promising plugin (in alpha as of Aug 2012)
http://www.cvast.tuwien.ac.at/projects/visualdebugging/ArrayExplorer 
But it freezes Eclipse for simple arrays beyond a few hundred elements.

I do use Detail formatters, but that still needs clicking on each element to see the values.

Are there any better ways to view this array/collection data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though i could not find a way to see them in nice table/array, i found a halfway workaround.

The solution is to define a static method in a throwaway class that takes the array as input and returns a string of concatenated values that one wants to quickly glance at. it could include the array index and newlines to view results formatted nicely. It can be fine tuned to print out only certain array indices to reduce clutter.

This static method can then be used in the watch area.

Comment: Hate to select my own half answer. But i have not got anything better. and i want to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'Expressions' tab.

There you can type in any number of expressions and have them evaluated in the current scope. 
ie: collection.size(), collection.getValueAt(i), ect...

Comment: True. That is the tedious part. I am trying to view multiple values simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

`Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Debug >Detail Formatter`

This may be close to what you are looking for. It is another tedious work to setup but once done you can see the value of objects in Expressions window.

Here is [link to start](https://dzone.com/articles/tips-and-tricks-debugging-ecli)

Comment: Thank you. Apologies if my question was not clear. I am looking for a way to look at multiple elements simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

override toString method of your class and you will be able to see what you want to see. i'm attaching example to show you exactly that.[image]